# Iris/Coq replacing literal

Tags: coq

I am using Iris for Coq, but I am stuck on something.
[image: Place I am stuck on]

Here, I want to get the snd value, l', from hd'. Then I can use IH with Hl and Hphi to finish the goal. Does anyone know how to replace hd' in the goal?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program (as in, the `heap_lang` code you are trying to verify) seems wrong. You are trying to get the second component of a location, which does not make sense, since locations are not pairs.

What your program should probably do here is load from the location, to get the pair that is stored in memory at location `#hd'`. In other words, instead of `Snd #hd'`, it should be `Snd (! #hd')`.

Once you fix your program, you can simply load from memory using `wp_load`. But this needs the load instruction (`!`) you are currently missing.